# When does 'touchscreen' and 'navigation' configuration changes trigger?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-configchanges

Reading through Android's documentation for [`android:configChanges`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config), I find:

```
"touchscreen"   The touchscreen has changed. (This should never normally happen.)
"navigation"    The navigation type (trackball/dpad) has changed. (This should never normally happen.)
```

Umm.. OK. So what does 'normally' mean here? Does it mean it *does* happen at times? Could someone give an example as to when this would trigger?

Comment: Hmm, I assume that it could change if someone plugs for instance a Hardware-Keyboard via USB (Navigation) or if another Monitor is plugged via HDMI

Comment: I use bluetooth buttons. They go into some kind of sleep mode after a while. When clicking a button then it wakes up and connects to the device. Then navigation configuration change happens. But I think some buttons trigger keyboard or keyboardHidden configuration change instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure @Rafael T is right. It all can be attached via USB. Or maybe in case of emergency it can be replaced "on a fly" by device repairer (with opened case and turned on device..) At least that's how I imagine

> "(This should never normally happen.)"